# Why can't I use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating an app that will send a notification. However when I use this line of code:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

It says:

Must be one or more of: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA, Intent.FILL_IN_CATEGORIES, Intent.FILL_IN_COMPONENT, Intent.FILL_IN_PACKAGE, Intent.FILL_IN_SOURCE_BOUNDS, Intent.FILL_IN_SELECTOR, Intent.FILL_IN_CLIP_DATA

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and maybe suggest a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Documentation | PendingIntent.getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)), the last parameter in `getActivity()` method `flags` can have only following flags of `int` type:
`FLAG_ONE_SHOT`
 `FLAG_NO_CREATE`
 `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`
 `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`
 or any of the flags as supported by [`Intent.fillIn()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#fillIn(android.content.Intent,%20int))which are:
`FILL_IN_ACTION`
 `FILL_IN_DATA`
 `FILL_IN_CATEGORIES`
 `FILL_IN_PACKAGE`
 `FILL_IN_COMPONENT`
 `FILL_IN_SOURCE_BOUNDS`
 `FILL_IN_SELECTOR` 
`FILL_IN_CLIP_DATA`
Hence, you can't use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in your `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method, so you must use this as a launch flag in your `Intent`.